# Pig - Filter a column twice in the same filter

Tags: filter, apache-pig

I'm trying to filter the same column twice. I basically want to only get the record in which one column is between the values of other 2 columns.

Imagine this:

```
(id,year_min,year_max,year)
(4470,1999,2001,2011)
(4471,2006,2013,2013)
```

So filtering like this it doesn't work:

```
filter1 = filter set by (year_min <= year and year_max >= year)
```

Is there another way of filtering it instead of breaking that filter into several ones?
Also, all the columns are bytearray.

PS: That is not the whole set but that is basically what I want to achieve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the **year_max** and **year** got swapped in your schema. It should be like this right? `id, year_min, year, year_max` but your schema says `id, year_min, year_max, year` . I modified the schema its works fine for me. Can you check it?

Comment: Actually, I really have to apologize. I filtered it but I wasn't looping through that filter to generate the final result. My schema works fine and yours should work too. It doesn't matter how it's displayed. You only have to consider the names of the fields.

Comment: Can you tell me what is not working? can you provide some more information?

Comment: What I had wrong was that I was doing the filter like so: filter1 = filter joining by (year_min <= listing_year and year_max >= listing_year) and (price_min <= listing_price and price_max >= listing_price); and then I was doing this:
alert_listings = foreach joining generate id as id(...)
instead of this
alert_listings = foreach filter1 generate id as id(...)
Mind the change in the foreach.
So there is no problem here. It works.